# how do i convert 'int [ ] ' type of list into an ArrayList without a for loop?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
public class r1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7};
       //convert this list x into an arraylist y         
       List<int[]> y = new ArrayList<>(y.toList(x)) ;
       System.out.print(y);
    }
}
```

1) I want to know a way of coverting a list defined as x, into an array list without using a for loop.

2) what is this type of list called? int[]? array? a list?

Comment: An `int []` would convert to a `List<Integer>` not to a `List<int[]>`.

Comment: If you really want a `List<int[]>`, then `Arrays.asList(intArr);` is enough

Comment: If you have access to `Java9+`, try using `List.of()`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer that would convert it to a List<Integer> not a List<Integer[]>

Comment: @Nicktar umm, for me that converts to `List<int[]>`. `List<Integer` throws a compile error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<int[]> to List<Integer>`

Comment: @Nexevis I don't think so

Comment: @XtremeBaumer don't know the definition of your `intArr` if it's the `x`from OPs code then `Arrays.asList(int[])` uses the contents of the supplied array to populate the list.

Comment: @Nicktar I don't know what you are using, but with this code: `int[] intArr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7 };`  definition, `List<int[]> asList = Arrays.asList(intArr);` is the only way to not cause a compiler error

Comment: @XtremeBaumer found it... different results com from `int[]` and `Integer[]` because `Arrays.asList` uses generics, and only works on objects because of this... `int` isn't an object while `Integer` is... Since OP's using ints for some reason, you're right.

Comment: For your question 2 - 'int[]' would be called an array of ints